# How to programmatically set selected in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display the current value of the select. But it displays nothing. How can I do it? This is my code for testing:

```
<div class="input-field col s12" ng-init="test=2">
        <label for="item_code" class="active">Category</label>
          <select 
            ng-model="test"
            ng-options="c.name for c in categories track by c.id"
          >
          </select>
          <p>This is the value {{test}}</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: the data is from the database my controller has this scope variable: $scope.categories = []; which contains array of object that contains id and name. The value looks like this: [{"id":1,name:"category 1"},{"id":2,name:"category 2"}];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<div class="input-field col s12" ng-init="test=2">
        <label for="item_code" class="active">Category</label>
          <select 
            ng-model="test"
            ng-options="c.name for c in categories track by c.id"
          >
          </select>
          <p>This is the value {{test}}</p>
      </div>
```

To Set select tag's default value use this:-

```
$socpe.test = {"id":1,name:"category 1"}
```

Comment: It works with this code: $scope.test = $scope.categories.find(function(e){
   return e.id==2;
  });but if I do this approach, I need to iterate $scope.categories to get the data something like that. Is there another way to do this using only the value of test?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're assigning the model as `test` (`ng-model="test"`), you need to use the same to display the value. Replace this:

```
<p>This is the value {{testSelect}}</p>
```

with this:

```
<p>This is the value {{test}}</p>
```

---

**Edit 1:**

As OP mentioned in the comments, he is using `ng-init="test=2"` to initialize the model `test`. The problem with this code is that in the `ng-options`, you're setting the `value` of `option`s with the `name` of the data. See this statement:

```
ng-options="c.name for c in categories track by c.id"
```

Since `c.name` doesn't match `2` anywhere, the dropdown doesn't select any element. Change `c.name` to `c.id` and it will start working:

```
ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in categories track by c.id"
```